# Excel function that returns values over multiple rows/columns

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I am trying to create excel VBA Sub-routine or function that returns values over multiple rows/columns as the case may be.

E.g. =DaysOfWeek()

if this formula is entered in Cell A1 then the result should be 
    A1 - Sunday
    A2 - Monday
    A3 - Tuesday

and so on .....

any link or any direction on this matter will be highly appreciated.

I dont know if its possible, but i sure have seen 3rd party formulae that return multiple rows/columns of data.

I really hope someone can drop some helpful pointers.

Much Appreciated.

**Edit:**  I am not looking for 7 calls to the function to get 7 days of the week.  In A1 i want to enter the UDF and A1 to A7 should get populated.

**Edit2 (21/Aug/2019):**  I did further reading on this and realised for the UDF to put a value somewhere it need to know which sheet, and which cell.  This will work if we use Application.Caller, which is supposed to tell the UDF where the result value has to be put(Namely which sheet and which cell).  But Application.Caller results in

> "Error 2023".

On further read i realised Application.caller can be called either through a button, or macro, or upon Auto_Open etc.  so tried this code as well :

```
Select Case TypeName(Application.Caller)
    Case "Range"
        Debug.Print Application.Caller.Parent.Name
    Case "String"
        Debug.Print Application.Caller
    Case "Error"
        Debug.Print "Error"
    Case Else
        Debug.Print "unknown"
End Select
```

And debug window shows

> Error.

I hope someone can help in this.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this UDF

```
 Option Explicit
  Function My_day(n As Byte)
  If n > 7 Then n = n Mod 7
  My_day = WeekdayName(n)
  End Function
```

in any cells try this Formula: 
 =My_day(COLUMNS($A$1:A1))   horizontally
        Or
=My_day(Rows($A$1:A1))       vertically

Comment: am not looking for 7 calls to the function to get 7 days of the week.

Comment: Write the Formula in just the first cell an drag down Or Left

Answer (score 0):

A UDF is not possible as far as I can see. I tried to make it work but it seem Microsoft has limited changes on the sheet to subs.

This sub will loop through the range you input and loop the weekdays as output in the inputed range.

```
Sub Day_Fill()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim DayNum As Integer

    Set rng = Range(InputBox("Input range")) ' Example A1:A10
    DayNum = InputBox("Startday, 1 = Sunday") ' 1-7
    For Each c In rng
        c.Value = WeekdayName(DayNum, False, vbSunday)
        If DayNum = 7 Then DayNum = 0
        DayNum = DayNum + 1
    Next c
End Sub
```

---

Last update.
This works with the selection.
You type what day you wnant to start with in the first cell and select the rest.

[image]

Then you rund the sub and it will give the following:

[image]

```
Sub Day_Fill()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim DayNum As Integer

    Set rng = Selection
    DayNum = Range(Split(rng.Address, ":")(0)).Value
    For Each c In rng
        c.Value = WeekdayName(DayNum, False, vbSunday)
        If DayNum = 7 Then DayNum = 0
        DayNum = DayNum + 1
    Next c
End Sub
```

Comment: This is good, but in this case i know there are 7 return values, but if that is not known then ??  or alternatively, to let the function know the cell that is calling it.  I tried using Application.caller but its giving me "Error 2023".

Comment: @user3129015 I'm not sure I understand what you mean.

Comment: a UDF for example, that gets called from lets say Book5(Z1) checks if Y1 has a date and gets the attendees on that date, it then checks if Y2 has a date and so on till it finds an empty cell.  In this case i cant be hard coding the first part of your function.  In other words i want the function to identify the cell that called it and then can use offset() to handle the rest of the work.

Comment: @Vinod It wasn't hardcoded. Either way a UDF is not possible. Updated the answer with a sub.

Comment: as function it will work fine and thanks for taking the effort to do that.  But i intend to use this function over more than 100 worksheets and the input box is not going to work.

Comment: Then use the selection range?

Comment: if the UDF is called 100 times in 30 or 40 sheets (which i probably might have to if it works out) then selection range will not work.

Comment: @Vinod Maybe, just maybe... you need to face what is possible instead of dreaming. I will make one last update.

Comment: thanks for the update and comment. I know what i want, and i guess it might be beyond you.  With this code you are completely missing out some obvious situations.  what if the user has selected some other part of the sheet to color the cells, and at that point if this function gets called what happens then ?  i had also said i might need to call this UDF quite a few times, have you considered what happens in that case?  Anyway thanks for your time and effort.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: Excel might crash at some point

### Use *Evaluate* to call a Sub in UDF

```
Option Explicit

Public Function DaysOfWeek(Destination As Range)
    ' Destination is the first cell of a desired range to be populated
    ActiveSheet.Evaluate "0+GetWeekDays(" & Destination.Address(False, False) & ")"
End Function

Public Sub GetWeekDays(Destination As Range)
    Destination.Cells(1).Resize(7, 1).Value = Application.Transpose(Array("Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"))
End Sub
```

Comment: when we call the function e.g. =VlookUp()  we do not specify the destination.  i just want the UDF to return whatever it returns (in this case 7 rows) without having to specify where or how many rows or columns.

Comment: @Vinod At this point you're asking the impossible. UDF doesn't know the address of the starting range cell without user input, compare it with `=ROW()` function rather than `=VLOOKUP()`.

Comment: @Vinod You can use get rid of `Destination` parameter by using `ActiveCell` as a default, but I can't guarantee any degree of efficiency.

Comment: active cell will not work cos if the UDF is called multiple times then it will be undesirable results.

Comment: @Vinod Can you please explain what on earth are you trying to achieve here? As far as I can see, you do not need a separate UDF for your task, you can include a simple Sub in your main routine, why make it a function? e.g. `With rCell : GetWeekDays(.Address(False, False)) : End With`?

Comment: DOW is an example, pls dont get locked into it.  If the UDF is for MonthsOfYear then it will return 12 rows, if the UDF is FactorsOf($b$5) then where ever this FactorsOf function gets called, that point and below rows i wish have to have all the factors of the value in cell B5.  I have clearly stated in the very first line what i wish to do, and i used DOW as an example.  My actual function is too complex to explain and i do not need help with the function implementation.  I just want help to to make a function return values across multiple rows.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:
Put the following formula in cell `A1` and then just drag down.
`=TEXT(TODAY()+ROW()-1,"dddd")`

Change `TODAY()` with your date e.g. "19.08.2019" (Use for local formating date)
`=TEXT("19.08.2019"+ROW()-1,"dddd")`

**Use this sub:**
Click on a range e.g. `A1` and then run the sub bellow.

```
Sub DaysOfWeek()
Range(Selection.Address).Offset(0, 0).Resize(7, 1).Value = 
Application.Transpose(Array("Sunday", _
"Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"))
End Sub
```

**Edit 1:**

```
Sub DaysOfWeek()
If Selection.Worksheet.Name = "Sheet1" Then
    Range(Selection.Address).Offset(0, 0).Resize(7, 1).Value = 
    Application.Transpose(Array("Sunday", _
"Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"))
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Drag and drop is not what am looking for.  do not want 7 function calls, but only 1 that gives 7 rows for this example.   if the function is made for MonthsOfYear then it will return 12 rows, if the UDF is FactorsOf($b$5) then where ever this FactorsOf function gets called, that point and below rows i wish have to have all the factors of the value in cell B5.  Hope this makes sense.

Comment: @Vinod Post a real example. I don't understand what value you have in `A1`, a date?

Comment: @Vinod You can try now.

Comment: what is rngName

Comment: Sorry, you can try now

Comment: yes as a function it works well and thank you for doing that.  But selection of area required for filling the data was never the pre-requisite.  this will fail if there are multiple calls to this Sub/Function across multiple sheets.  I appreciate your effort thou and thank you.

Comment: My solution is the right answer for your question so you can accept my answer. If you have another question, make another post. Thank you

Comment: i tried to use this function in a workbook and i get the error circular reference.  This will also fail if there are multiple calls or if the selection is else where in the sheet where you want to enter some data and when a refresh happens your code will mess the sheet.

Comment: If you give me the name of the sheet you'll solve this problem

Comment: Change "Sheet1" with your sheet name

Comment: How do I now where is ok in the workspace to put the data, you didn't metion that...you can specified now to change the code